# PHP date_create / date_diff only works with american date-format?

Tags: php, date, time, date-format, time-format

So I have two form fields containing dates.

Using jQuery-UI Datepicker, I set their format do `dd/mm/yy`.

I use a function that return me the days between two dates:

```
function getDaysBetween($date1, $date2){
    $datetime1 = date_create($date1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date2);
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    return $interval->days;
}
```

I alert the value afterwards for debugging purposes.

So, If my date is in dd/mm/yy format, php returns the following for startdate = 01/04/2016 and enddate = 03/04/2016.

[image]

If my dates are in mm/dd/yy format however, it is correctly:

[image]

Why?

Comment: Use `DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date)` instead. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: The accepted date and time formats of `date_create()` are [well documented](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php#refsect1-datetime.construct-parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [**`DateTime::createFromFormat`**](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead of `date_create()`.

So, modify your `getDaysBetween()` function like this :

```
function getDaysBetween($date1, $date2, $format = 'd-m-Y'){
    $datetime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date1);
    $datetime2 = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date2);
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    return $interval->days;
}
```

Then, you can use that function like this for dates formatted as `d-m-Y` :

```
getDaysBetween('01-02-2016', '01-04-2016')); // -> OUTPUTS int(60)
```

If your input is in a format different from `d-m-Y`, just pass along the format as an extra parameter.

Some examples :

```
getDaysBetween('3-2-2016', '15-5-2016', 'j-n-Y'); // -> OUTPUTS int(102)


getDaysBetween('9-Dec-2015', '28-Mar-2015', 'j-M-Y'); // -> OUTPUTS int(256)


getDaysBetween('15/8/24', '15/11/18', 'y/m/d'); // -> OUTPUTS int(86)
```

See [**the documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) for an overview of the supported formats.

Answer (score 0):

You should use date "YYYY-MM-DD" in your Database anyway, so you can make a request to sort by date. So you just have to set your timezone and use date_diff. And after if you want to output them like MM-DD-YYYY just use

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Montreal');

$date_a = new DateTime('2016-02-01');
$date_b = new DateTime('2016-04-01');

$interval = date_diff($date_a, $date_b);

echo $interval->format('%d');

echo date('m-d-Y', strtotime('2016-02-01'));
```